# Tuxedo tmshutdown stops server but process still exists

Tags: oracle, ipc, shared-memory, middleware, tuxedo

i've got problem with tuxedo tmshutdown command. One of processes still runs (with huge cpu usage) though tmshutdown stops it succesfull. There is also one opened IPC shared memory which i can close when I kill existing process. There are other servers but only this one is problematic. Is it possible that the problem is in code (tpsvrdone is exiting without errors)?

Answer (score 0):

Tmshudown normally sends a SIGTERM signal to tuxedo serves unless you use `-k KILL` (which sends a `SIGKILL`)

If the source code of the Tuxedo server implements a handler of the signal, you could get the behavior you  explained.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/

Also, if it is not possible to shutdown a server, or remove a service advertisement, a diagnostic is written on the ULOG.